# How can i take data one line at a time from a txt file and use it as a variable to send requests?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I'm currently working on a small side project that I thought was cool. However, I've reached a big road blockage. I'm trying to get it to read a username from a text file and upload it to an API, however, I keep getting error code 400 with a server response stating that the username field was empty in the request. I also added a print statement to confirm the credential variable was set correctly, and it was making me think it was a communication error from me to the API. I think another problem may be that I set the content type to "plain/text". I ran Wireshark to see the exact request I made, and it looks like everything is scrunched together. Here is my current code:

```
import requests
import time

with open('./user.txt', 'r') as f:
    creds = f.read()

print(f"Current User: {creds}")

url = 'http://example.com/api'
data = {f"nickname":"{creds}","password":"{creds}","email":"","referral":"null"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}

response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I'm pretty new to using the requests library, so I'm sorry if this is a bad question to ask, but any help will be really appreciated.

Wireshark states that my request data is `nickname=%7Bcreds%7D&password=%7Bcreds%7D`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import requests
import json

with open('./user.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        creds = line.strip()
        print(f"Current User: {creds}")

        url = 'http://example.com/api'
        data = {f"nickname":"{creds}","password":"{creds}","email":"","referral":"null"}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.text)
```

Comment: i just added in the code, and i still got error 400. The list only has 3 usernames for testing. Could this possibly an issue with the header content type, or with the way i listed the data variable?

Comment: You can try checking if the `content-type` header you're using is correct for the request your are trying to send. And have you tried `response.status_code` and  `reponse.text` to see the more details about your error? I've added it to the code once again if you'd like to test it once more. And yes it is as you said your text/plain might also be the issue if the server is expecting something else.

Comment: On the response and on the API page it says it's looking for JSON. but how can i send JSON with requests? and it seems like it's already in JSON format too.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that seemed to be the issue text/plain was the wrong thing. I'll edit the code above to add the json.

Comment: Check the code I've edit above. All you had to do was change it to `application/json` and not what you had being `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my header type! I didn't need to use `JSON` or `plain/text`. I used `application/x-www-form-urlencoding`, which I got from the file's history. The application now reads each username and password, and sends it to the server!